# Can't remove item from list, but it clearly is there

Tags: python

I've been reading Automate the Boring Stuff with Python and I'm currently stuck at the project of generating random quizzes. I am aware of the fact that the book itself gives you an example how to do it, but I always try to give it a go on my own. But this time, I can't bring myself to an explanation of why my script is not working (I will paste the whole code that is relevant so you guys can try it yourselves).

A quick explanation of how my code is supposed to work: first, it opens and writes some stuff in a couple of files (not the point) then, it stores the keys from the dictionary "pairs" into the variables "states" as a list. Immediately after it shuffles the order of the items in "states" so each test has a different order of "states". The next for loop (for j in states[:]:) I use "states[:]" instead of just "states" because I want to modify the list "states" so it doesn't affect my loop. Then I add another loop, to generate the options for each question in the quiz. I remove the "j" item in "states[:]" from "states", so "states[:]" remains unaltered and "states" has one less item (the one that is the right answer). At least that's how it should work, but it doesn't, the program just tells me that the "j" item is not in "states".

```
import random

pairs = {'Alabama': 'Montgomery', 'Alaska': 'Juneau', 'Arizona': 'Phoenix',
'Arkansas': 'Little Rock', 'California': 'Sacramento', 'Colorado': 'Denver',
'Connecticut': 'Hartford', 'Delaware': 'Dover', 'Florida': 'Tallahassee',
'Georgia': 'Atlanta', 'Hawaii': 'Honolulu', 'Idaho': 'Boise', 'Illinois':
'Springfield', 'Indiana': 'Indianapolis', 'Iowa': 'Des Moines', 'Kansas':
'Topeka', 'Kentucky': 'Frankfort', 'Louisiana': 'Baton Rouge', 'Maine':
'Augusta', 'Maryland': 'Annapolis', 'Massachusetts': 'Boston', 'Michigan':
'Lansing', 'Minnesota': 'Saint Paul', 'Mississippi': 'Jackson', 'Missouri':
'Jefferson City', 'Montana': 'Helena', 'Nebraska': 'Lincoln', 'Nevada':
'Carson City', 'New Hampshire': 'Concord', 'New Jersey': 'Trenton',
'New Mexico': 'Santa Fe', 'New York': 'Albany', 'North Carolina': 'Raleigh',
'North Dakota': 'Bismarck', 'Ohio': 'Columbus', 'Oklahoma': 'Oklahoma City',
'Oregon': 'Salem', 'Pennsylvania': 'Harrisburg', 'Rhode Island': 'Providence',
'South Carolina': 'Columbia', 'South Dakota': 'Pierre', 'Tennessee':
'Nashville', 'Texas': 'Austin', 'Utah': 'Salt Lake City', 'Vermont':
'Montpelier', 'Virginia': 'Richmond', 'Washington': 'Olympia',
'West Virginia': 'Charleston', 'Wisconsin': 'Madison', 'Wyoming': 'Cheyenne'}

alternatives = [ "A", "B", "C", "D"]
for i in range(1): #each quiz
    quiz = open("Quiz number %s.txt" % (i + 1), "w")
    quiz.write(" "*16 + "STATE CAPITALS QUIZ\nTest %s" % (i + 1) + "\n")
    quiz_answers = open("Answers for Quiz %s.txt" % (i + 1), "w")

    states = list(pairs.keys())
    random.shuffle(states)

    for j in states[:]: #each question
        options = []
        quiz.write("\n%s" % (states[:].index(j) + 1) + ". What is the capital of " + j + "?\n")
        quiz_answers.write("%s" % (states[:].index(j) + 1) + ". " + pairs[j] + "\n")

        options.append(pairs[j]) #adds correct capital to options
        print(j)  #I added this line to see if the object j was a string
        print(states) #I added this line to see if states was indeed a list

        for k in range(3):
            if j in states: #finally, i added an if statement to see if the item j was in the list states
                print("fk") # and it does check out everytime I run the code
            states.remove(j)
            options.append(pairs[states[k]])
            pass
        random.shuffle(options)
```

This is exactly what my code looks like.

Now, the problem is, in the third for loop (for k in range(3)). I try to remove an item but the program throws an error, precisely : "ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list".
I put an if statement right before the .remove() and every time I run the code it runs its content and prints "fk", meaning that the object that I'm trying to remove does actually belong to the list I'm trying to remove it from.

I would love if someone can give me an explanation to why this is happening and how could I correct it, without changing too much of the code (unless it's necessary of course). I also tried importing the copy module and using deepcopy, but I think it is the same as just using the [:], so anyway, all help is appreciated! Thank you

Comment: Since this is in a loop, are you sure that the `if` statement is printing on the same iterations that the `.remove` method is failing? How have you determined this? It would be best if you could simplify this down to a [mcve], since the code is doing a lot of other things than just demonstrating the error.

Comment: You are calling `states.remove(j)` *three times*, in a loop, without changing `j`.  Of course the item isn't going to be found on the second time through!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you're trying to remove the same element three times:

```py
        for k in range(3):
            if j in states:
                print("fk")
            states.remove(j)
            options.append(pairs[states[k]])
            pass
```

Notice that nothing in this loop changes the value of `j`. So:

- On the first iteration, `j` is in the list, you print `fk`, and you remove `j` successfully.
- On the second iteration, `j` is already removed, so nothing is printed, and the `ValueError` is raised because it isn't there any more.
- There is no third iteration because the `ValueError` has already been raised.

Logically, it doesn't make sense to remove `j` three times. You should move the `states.remove(j)` statement outside of the loop, either before or after, whichever is appropriate for what your program is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because you put it outside the if statement. so it isn't doing the check (if x is in state)

```
for k in range(3):
    if j in states: #finally, i added an if statement to see if the item j was in the list states
         print("fk") # and it does check out everytime I run the code
         states.remove(j)
```